# has Datamapper any analog to rails sexy validations?

Tags: validation, sinatra, datamapper

Is there analog to set validations like this:
validates :title, :presence => true, :format => :regex, :uniqueness => true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the way Rails does. But it's quite sexy, that you get some validations automagically, for example when setting a field to `:required => true`. See http://datamapper.org/docs/validations.html for more examples.

Manual validations cannot be specified as a single hash parameter to `validates`. I guess this might be, because there are a lot of options to validations in DataMapper and DataMapper would have to sort out which option belongs to which validation.

But if you like you can still build your own `validation` Method which does exactly the same thing (also described in the above link).

Also, you could simply use ActiveRecord with Sinatra if you like its features.